# Why am I getting a "CustomField not found" error when deploying a globalValueSet called "Country" in Winter 17

Tags: deployment, error

When I try to deploy a GlobalValueSet (formerly known as 'global picklist') named Country in Winter '17 (API v38) I get a "CustomField not found" deployment error. How can I resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably an internal bug in Salesforce v38 similar to this issue https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000001BZ1QAM

Best workaround is to rename that global picklist to "Countries" or something similar.